# bash - errors trying to pipe commands to run to separate function

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, job-scheduling, variable-expansion

I'm trying to get this function for making it easy to parallelize my bash scripts working.  The idea is simple; instead of running each command sequentially, I pipe the command I want to run to this function and it does while read line; run the jobs in the bg for me and take care of logistics.... it doesn't work though.  I added set -x by where stuff's executed and it looks like I'm getting weird quotes around the stuff I want executed... what should I do?

```
runParallel () {
    while read line
    do
        while [ "`jobs | wc -l`" -eq 8 ]
        do
            sleep 2
        done

        {
            set -x
            ${line}
            set +x
        } &
    done

    while [ "`jobs | wc -l`" -gt 0 ] 
    do
        sleep 1
        jobs >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        echo sleeping
    done
}

for H in `ypcat hosts | grep fmez | grep -v mgmt | cut -d\  -f2 | sort -u`
do
    echo 'ping -q -c3 $H 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null && echo $H - UP || echo $H - DOWN'
done | runParallel
```

When I run it, I get output like the following:

```
> ./myscript.sh
+ ping -q -c3 '$H' '2>/dev/null' '1>/dev/null' '&&' echo '$H' - UP '||' echo '$H' - DOWN
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaA] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface or address]
            [-M mtu discovery hint] [-S sndbuf]
            [ -T timestamp option ] [ -Q tos ] [hop1 ...] destination
+ set +x
sleeping
>
```

Comment: What's wrong with letting make do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes in the `set -x` output are not the problem, at most they are another result of the problem. The main problem is that `${line}` is not the same as `eval ${line}`.

When a variable is expanded, the resulting words are not treated as shell reserved constructs. And this is expected, it means that eg.

```
A="some text containing > ; && and other weird stuff"
echo $A
```

does not shout about invalid syntax but prints the variable value.

But in your function it means that all the words in `${line}`, including `2>/dev/null` and  the like, are passed as arguments to ping, which `set -x` output nicely shows, and so ping complains.

If you want to execute from variables complicated commandlines with redirections and conditionals, you will have to use `eval`.

Comment: That's awesome.  Putting double quotes around the text that's echoed and using eval got it working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you probably don't want single quotes in your echo command. Single quotes are literal strings, and don't interpret your bash variable $H.

Answer (score 1):

Like many users of GNU Parallel you seem to have written your own parallelizer.

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
cat hosts | parallel -j8 'ping -q -c3 {} 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null && echo {} - UP || echo {} - DOWN'
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 0):

[Put your command in an array.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)